# How to write the id of the Android item you are creating to the Firebase database

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I use the Realtime DataBase. Java.
The problem is that I can't get the created ID. I have a user who creates an order:

[image]

The created order is entered in the database

[image]

It includes information, the sender's ID, and must also have its own ID shown in the screenshot, which is what I have a problem with.

Order creation code below

```
    private EditText mDateField, mModelField, mProblemField, mAdressField;
    private Button mConfirm;
    private FirebaseUser fuser;
    @Override     
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);

    mDateField = findViewById(R.id.date);
    mModelField = findViewById(R.id.model);
    mProblemField= findViewById(R.id.problem_desc);
    mAdressField = findViewById(R.id.adress);
    mConfirm = findViewById(R.id.confirm);
    fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    final String userID = fuser.getUid();
    final String orderid = "";


    mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String date = mDateField.getText().toString();
            String model = mModelField.getText().toString();
            String adress = mAdressField.getText().toString();
            String problem = mProblemField.getText().toString();
            saveOrderInformation(orderid,userID,date,model,adress,problem);
            finish();
            AppUtilities.showToast(OrderActivity.this,"Order");
        }
    });
}

private void  saveOrderInformation(String id, String sender, String date, String model, String adress, String problem){

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    HashMap<String,Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("id",id);
    hashMap.put("sender",sender);
    hashMap.put("date",date);
    hashMap.put("model",model);
    hashMap.put("adress",adress);
    hashMap.put("problem",problem);
    reference.child("Orders").push().setValue(hashMap);
}
}
```

Comment: To me its very clear, you did not set the order id, hence it is still empty string.

Comment: I can't figure out how to fill it out. So I made it empty.

Comment: what is the id supposed to be?

Comment: -M3pu-wJsQngveSplA9a

Comment: I'm creating an order. It gets an id. I need this id to be written inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `push()` to be also the value of the attribute `id`, then you can try the following:

```
private void  saveOrderInformation(String id, String sender, String date, String model, String adress, String problem){

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    String key = reference.child("Orders").push().getKey();

    HashMap<String,Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("id",key);
    hashMap.put("sender",sender);
    hashMap.put("date",date);
    hashMap.put("model",model);
    hashMap.put("adress",adress);
    hashMap.put("problem",problem);
    reference.child("Orders").child(key).setValue(hashMap);  
   }
```

You can get the `push()` value using `getKey()` and then you can assign it to `id` and use it as reference when setting the value.

Comment: There was progress, but still not that. For ID -M454_I2_Q5pHgyLgmlO came the key -M454_I0YtpkckeN6woY

Comment: U should use the `key` here also `reference.child("Orders").child(key).setValue(hashMap)`..

Answer (score 0):

id is blank because you've set it to blank on `final String orderid = "";`
Either, you can delete that line or you can remove the sender column in the database and set it to id.
Or if you want to set the orderID as id in the database. Then use the below function to obtain the id

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Orders");
String id = reference.push().getKey();
```

and set this id to id in the database by

```
    HashMap<String,Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("id",id);
    hashMap.put("sender",sender);
    hashMap.put("date",date);
    hashMap.put("model",model);
    hashMap.put("adress",adress);
    hashMap.put("problem",problem);
```

and then insert the entire dataset into the database by

```
reference.child(id).setValue(hashMap);
```